LDS Holy Ghost god without body
It was brought up in a comment to an answer1 that the Holy Ghost as a personage of spirit contradicts the Church of LDS doctrine that a body is required for godhood.
How does the LDS church reconcile these contradicting beliefs.
1 https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/103687/22319

To clarify the two beliefs:

Holy Ghost has body of spirit only (TRUE):

22 The Father has a body of flesh and bones as tangible as man’s; the Son also; but the Holy Ghost has not a body of flesh and bones, but is a personage of Spirit. Were it not so, the Holy Ghost could not dwell in us.(D&C 130:22)


Physical body required to gain godhood (PARTIAL):
This is slightly twisted or misunderstood doctrine. Yes those who 'become like God'(gain exaltation) will have physical bodies, but so will everyone else (see Gospel Topics: salvation). The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints believe that the resurrection

...shall come to all, because of Christ’s victory over death.

Then Elder Russell M Nelson spoke on the difference:

Resurrection, or immortality, comes to every man and every woman as an unconditional gift.
Eternal life, or celestial glory or exaltation, is a conditional gift. Conditions of this gift have been established by the Lord, who said, “If you keep my commandments and endure to the end you shall have eternal life, which gift is the greatest of all the gifts of God.”

On what has been revealed about the personage of the Holy Ghost/Spirit, not much has been revealed. This question asks when will the Holy Spirit gain a body, with the tldr being we don't know. There is a lack of LDS revelation on this subject. There are plenty of theories/speculation:

The Holy Ghost will at some point gain a physical body

analogy: to travel overseas you need a airline ticket and a passport, the order in which you gain them is not important, you need both before you can reach your destination
if this is the case, the Holy Ghost will eventually gain a body (a body is not required to be part of the godhead-see last statement)


The Holy Ghost is not a child of God (Jesus Christ is referred to as the Only Begotten of God, and we are children of God, but no familial titles seem to refer to the Holy Ghost), and there is some other plan/path for him

The Holy Ghost could be a position/title/office that rotates (see answer to other question for this theory)
if this is the case, the Holy Ghost may/may not gain a body. If the Holy Ghost is an office than technically the office wouldn't gain a body, but members that held that office would have. If Holy Ghost isn't an office, there is not enough information to draw conclusions



However there is NO definitive doctrine on when/how/if the Holy Ghost will gain a body.
The Plan of Salvation does state:

The plan includes all the laws and ordinances of the gospel necessary to gain eternal life, “the greatest of all the gifts of God.”
...
We are on earth because we chose to follow Heavenly Father’s plan. One significant purpose of mortality is to gain a physical body. On earth we can have joy and peace, but we will also face temptation, opposition, and adversity and experience trials. Earthly trials are part of mortality and can help us grow to be more like our Heavenly Father.

A different article The Salvation of Little Children Who Die, What We Do and Don't Know states

“Joseph Smith taught the doctrine that the infant child that was laid away in death would come up in the resurrection as a child; and, pointing to the mother of a lifeless child, he said to her: ‘You will have the joy, the pleasure, and satisfaction of nurturing this child, after its resurrection, until it reaches the full stature of its spirit.’ There is restitution, there is growth, there is development, after the resurrection from death. I love this truth. It speaks volumes of happiness, of joy and gratitude to my soul. Thank the Lord he has revealed these principles to us.”
Not only will little children reach full maturity; they will also reach full exaltation. Abinadi taught that “little children also have eternal life” (Mosiah 15:25). The Prophet Joseph Smith taught that “you shall have your children; for they shall have eternal life, for their debt is paid.”

I bring these 2 articles up to mention that while gaining a body, at some point, is needed the length of having a body has no restrictions (please do not read more into this statement, the second article is specifically about little children under the age of accountability).
Remember that Jesus Christ was considered a member of the Godhead in the pre-existence when He didn't have a body, so having a body is not a requirement for being a member of the Godhead (we don't know the requirements, just who makes it up). Much like we/man have and have had a divine identity (Romans 8:16-17) since the pre-existence, when we didn't have bodies. Divine identity does not require having a body either, the same can probably be applied to the Holy Ghost.



From Doctrines of Salvation:

AVOID SPECULATING ON DESTINY OF THE SPIRIT. The Holy Ghost is not a personage with a body of flesh and bones, and in this respect differs from the Father and the Son. The Holy Ghost is not a woman, as some have declared, and therefore is not the mother of Jesus Christ.
It is a waste of time to speculate in relation to his jurisdiction. We know what has been revealed and that the Holy Ghost, sometimes spoken of as the Holy Spirit, and Comforter, is the third member of the Godhead, and that he, being in perfect harmony with the Father and the Son, reveals to man by the spirit of revelation and prophecy the truths of the gospel of Jesus Christ. Our great duty is so to live that we may be led constantly in light and truth by this Comforter so that we may not be deceived by the many false spirits that are in the world.
I have never troubled myself about the Holy Ghost whether he will sometime have a body or not because it is not in any way essential to my salvation. He is a member of the Godhead, with great power and authority, with a most wonderful mission which must be performed by a spirit. This has satisfied me without delving into mysteries that would be of no particular benefit.



This is a very useful compilation of source material, +1
